# Ressources for HAProxy on heavy load

Tags: hardware, haproxy, max-requests

What are the main ressources HAProxy needs handling millions of requests per hour? What hardware is recommended (CPU, Cored, Ram...)?

Answer (score 2):

If millions of requests per hour (~300 rps), then entry-level servers will be fine, maybe single Intel Xeon + 8GB RAM.

If it's an API-balancing server, Gigabit Ethernet is fine.  If it's a file download server with ~300rps, maybe choose 10Gbps network card.

Comment: Thanks Gea-Suan Lin. With these numbers I can do some calculations :)

Comment: One more question: If it's a file download server with ~300rps why to choose a 10Gbps network card? I thought the traffic is distributed between the different servers.